# MPIR coding error

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

Hi i've tried using mpir(a library) for my code. I've changed my code and converted everything to work with mpir. My code consists of a series of loops within loops and equations that are dependent upon each other so it's incredibly difficult to spot a mistake. I ran the code after debugging and it worked fine for the first 500 iterations of a certain loop then i got the following message:

GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=24)
Press any key to continue . . .

I have no idea of the cause of this problem. Is it related to memory? If it worked fine for the initial iterations then why should there be a problem now if it isn't memory?

I created the code again and it ran further this time. It went for the first 2000 iterations before giving the message:

GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=16)
Press any key to continue . . .

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you already know. It's most likely a memory leak.

See section 3.7 of the manual for [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/mpir-2.6.0.pdf):

> mpz_t and mpq_t variables never reduce their allocated space. Normally
>   this is the best policy, since it avoids frequent reallocation.
>   Applications that need to return memory to the heap at some particular
>   point can use mpz_realloc2 , or clear variables no longer needed.

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), a tool for helping to debug memory leaks, may also be helpful. Good luck.